# How to add extra HTML to columnFormat on Fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fullcalendar

I am using full calendar `basicWeek` and using `columnFormat: 'dd D'` which producing the html like:

```
<th class="fc-day-header ui-widget-header fc-sat fc-future" data-date="2016-12-10">
 <span>Sa 10</span>
</th>
```

I want to style this data `Sa` and `10` as different color. So I think, best is to change markup. Seeking suggestion from expert.

**Want to make like:**

[image: Want like this]

**Currently looks like:**

[image: Currently looks like this:]

Comment: do you want each piece inside the span with different colors or the entire content of the span with the same color?

Comment: I want to add different color for day name(e.g: Mo) and different for date(e.g: 5)

Comment: then you right, you need to split the content of the header... however the plugin does not allow that out of the box, I think you may need to modify the plugin for this... or run `javascript` that does the trick after render.... but it would look a bit glitchy...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, it is not out of the box functionality, but you can try something like this:

```
var $calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  header: {
    left: 'prev,next today',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
  },
  defaultView: 'basicWeek',
  dayRender: function(date, cell) {
    var today = new Date();
    var cellIndex = cell[0].cellIndex
    var h = cell.closest('table').find('th').eq(cellIndex);
    if (date.getDate() === today.getDate()) {
      h.html('<span class="c1">' + moment(date).format("ddd") + '</span>&nbsp;<span class="c2">' + moment(date).format("M/D") + '</span>');
    } else {
      h.addClass('c1');
    }
  }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ogaydvos/